# How to assign a list of latitude and longitude to a list of type Marker in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list of type `Map<String, dynamic>` named `positionMarkers` which holds latitudes and longitudes along with their ID's that I would like to map accordingly into a list of type Marker i.e `List<Marker>`. I need the id in `positionMarkers` and the lat and lng to go into `MarkerId()` and `LatLng()` respectively. I'm pretty sure that this can be achieved by using loops but cannot seem to figure how. Any help would be appreciated:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapMarkers with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> positionMarkers = [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'lat': 22.6434340,
      'lng': 88.446740,
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'lat': 22.6435442,
      'lng': 88.456742,
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'lat': 22.6436544,
      'lng': 88.466744,
    },
    {
      'id': 4,
      'lat': 22.6437646,
      'lng': 88.476746,
    },
    {'id': 5, 'lat': 22.6438748, 'lng': 88.486748}
  ];

  final List<Marker> markers = [
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(),
      position: LatLng(),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(),
    )
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```dart
final List<Marker> markers = [];

void _createMarkers() {
  for (int i = 0; i < positionMarkers.length; i++) {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(positionMarkers[i]['id']),
        position: LatLng(positionMarkers[i]['lat'], positionMarkers[i]['lng']),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Marker ${positionMarkers[i]['id']}',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    final List<Marker> markers = List.empty(growable: true);
    for (var i in positionMarkers) {
      // markerId is i["id]
      // lat is i["lat"]
      // lng is i["lng"]
      markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(i["id"]),
          position: LatLng(i["lat"], i["lng"]),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(),
        ),
      );
    }
```